# Is there a way to start playing an MP4 video file while downloading in iOS?

Tags: ios, video-streaming, avplayer

I have a big MP4 video file in Dropbox. Is there a way to start playing that while downloading in iOS?

Thanks

Comment: @H2CO3, how to implement it? thanks

Comment: you start playing it (`MPMoviePlayerViewController`, maybe?), then you download it parallel, in a different thread (`NSURLConnection` may come in handy).

Comment: @H2CO3,it's not the most efficient way, since you could consume double data

Comment: I was not concerned with "efficiency".

Answer (score -1):

Use an `NSURLConnection` to async download the content of the video `URL` into a local file and after a certain fraction has been downloaded (approx. 2 MB), play the file. `NSURLConnection` with `connection:didReceiveData` `delegate` method does the job